# eBay Trading API export complete conversation

Tags: ebay-api

I am currently endeavoring to export an entire conversation using the eBay API, however, I am encountering difficulties in finding an effective solution. The challenge lies in the fact that the system only allows for the exportation of received messages.

Here is the process I have been employing thus far:

```
 body = """
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GetMyMessagesRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
<RequesterCredentials>
<eBayAuthToken>{token}</eBayAuthToken>
</RequesterCredentials>
<DetailLevel>ReturnHeaders</DetailLevel>
</GetMyMessagesRequest>
""".format(token=token)
```

I initiate a request to retrieve the headers, aiming to obtain the message IDs. Subsequently, I proceed to request the corresponding messages.

```
 body = """
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GetMyMessagesRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
<RequesterCredentials>
<eBayAuthToken>{token}</eBayAuthToken>
</RequesterCredentials>
<MessageIDs>
<MessageID>{msg_id}</MessageID>
</MessageIDs>
<DetailLevel>ReturnMessages</DetailLevel>
</GetMyMessagesRequest>
""".format(token=token, msg_id=msg_id)
```

I am currently receiving messages through HTML, a method I find rather perplexing. This process allows me to export the received messages from the HTML and view my sent messages within the history. However, this method is far from ideal as it does not present the conversation in chronological order, a feature I find crucial for my needs.

I am not fond of this system and am in search of a more efficient solution that will allow me to export my conversations in a chronological manner.

If anyone has a more effective solution, I would greatly appreciate your input.

Best regards.

Comment: I just saw that when you are logged into ebay and click on a conversation (in the new ebay view) a GET request is sent to ebay that looks something like this:
https://www.ebay.de/cnt/ViewMessage/ajax/conversation?conversation_id=45454545454&group_type=CORE

you will get a nice JSON response containing the full conversation. I hope ebay will add this to the API in the near future. Until then, I guess I'll be programming my own interface.